# WordPress Layer Slider YouTube video embbed

Tags: wordpress

I have using Layer Slider WordPress plugin and added YouTube embed code snippet for showing YouTube video as one slide. i have using a code snippet like below in one layer of this slider,

```html
<iframe width="1400" height="400" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/E5ln4uR4TwQ?autoplay=0&rel=0&ecver=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

it's working. but how to set auto play stop option in video.

also tested the below code by placed &autoplay=0 at the end of the ID.

```html
<iframe width="1400" height="400" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/E5ln4uR4TwQ&autoplay=0&rel=0&ecver=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Thanks

Comment: you have use autoplay=0 as the Youtube Video Controls. Either 0 or 1 and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

LayerSlider WP plugin has an option to autoload videos, which can be overriding the autoplay parameter of your embed video.

In the slider you want to put the video, go in the "Slider settings" tab and then choose the "Videos" submenu to enable or disable this option:

[image]